# Getting a better answer from sympy inverse laplace transform

Tags: python, sympy

Trying to compute the following lines I'm getting a realy complex result.

```
from sympy import *
s = symbols("s")
t = symbols("t")
h = 1/(s**3 + s**2/5 + s)
inverse_laplace_transform(h,s,t)
```

The result is the following:

```
(-(I*exp(-t/10)*sin(3*sqrt(11)*t/10) - exp(-t/10)*cos(3*sqrt(11)*t/10))*gamma(-3*sqrt(11)*I/5)*gamma(-1/10 - 3*sqrt(11)*I/10)/(gamma(9/10 - 3*sqrt(11)*I/10)*gamma(1 - 3*sqrt(11)*I/5)) + (I*exp(-t/10)*sin(3*sqrt(11)*t/10) + exp(-t/10)*cos(3*sqrt(11)*t/10))*gamma(3*sqrt(11)*I/5)*gamma(-1/10 + 3*sqrt(11)*I/10)/(gamma(9/10 + 3*sqrt(11)*I/10)*gamma(1 + 3*sqrt(11)*I/5)) + gamma(1/10 - 3*sqrt(11)*I/10)*gamma(1/10 + 3*sqrt(11)*I/10)/(gamma(11/10 - 3*sqrt(11)*I/10)*gamma(11/10 + 3*sqrt(11)*I/10)))*Heaviside(t)
```

However the answer should be simpler, [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse%20laplace%20transform1%2F%28s**3%20%2B%20s**2%2F5%20%2B%20s%29) proves it.

Is there any way to simplify this result?

Comment: Given that  sympy isn't as developed as WolframAlpha, so it's not surprising that it's answer isn't as simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried a bit with this one and the way I could find a simpler solution is using something like:

```
from sympy import *
s = symbols("s")
t = symbols("t", positive=True)
h = 1/(s**3 + s**2/5 + s)
inverse_laplace_transform(h,s,t).evalf().simplify()
```

Notice that I define t as a positive variable, otherwise the sympy function returns a large term followed by the Heaviaside function. The result still contains many gamma functions that I could not reduce to the expression returned by Wolfram. Using evalf() some of those are converted to their numeric value and then after simplification you get a expression similar like the one in Wolfram but with floating numbers.

Unfortunately this part of Sympy is not quite mature. I also tried with Maxima and the result is quite close to the one in Wolfram. So it seems that Wolfram is not doing anything really special there.